# how to get scrollable html table in phonegap application

Tags: cordova

I want to scroll html table in phonegap application ,i tried using div tag but it does not work in phone gap but same code work in safari browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this jquery plugin for iscroll,
usage: add data-iscroll="enable" to your page.

```
<div style="height:as u need;>
            <div data-iscroll="scroller">

      // your table put here.
       </div>
     </div>

    (function($) {
     $(function() {

       var SafariWindowHeightFix = 34; // XXX:

       function fixed(elm) {
       if (elm.data("iscroll-plugin")) {
       return;
       }

       elm.css({
               overflow: 'hidden'
               });

       var barHeight = 0;
       var $header = elm.find('[data-role="header"]');
       if ($header.length) {
       $header.css({
                   "z-index": 1000,
                   padding: 0,
                   width: "100%"
                   });
       barHeight += $header.height();
       }

       var $footer = elm.find('[data-role="footer"]');
       if ($footer.length) {
       $footer.css({
                   "z-index": 1000,
                   padding: 0,
                   width: "100%"
                   }); 
       barHeight += $footer.height();
       }

       var $wrapper = elm.find('[data-role="content"]');
       if ($wrapper.length) {
       $wrapper.css({
                    "z-index": 1,"height":"600px"
                    });
       $wrapper.height($(window).height() - barHeight - SafariWindowHeightFix);
       $wrapper.bind('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); });
       }
       var scroller = elm.find('[data-iscroll="scroller"]').get(1);
       var scroller1 = elm.find('[data-iscroll="scroller"]').get(0);

       if (scroller) {
       var iscroll = new iScroll(scroller, {desktopCompatibility:true});
       elm.data("iscroll-plugin", iscroll);
       }
       if (scroller1) {
       var iscroll1 = new iScroll(scroller1, {desktopCompatibility:true});
       elm.data("iscroll-plugin", iscroll1);
       } 
       }
       $('[data-role="page"][data-iscroll="enable"]').live("pageshow", function() {
                                                           fixed($(this));
                                                           });
       $('[data-role="dialog"][data-iscroll="enable"]').live("pageshow", function() {
                                                             fixed($(this));
                                                             }); 
       if ($.mobile.activePage.data("iscroll") == "enable") {
       fixed($.mobile.activePage);
       }
       });
     })(jQuery);
```